# Node host configuration

Tags: node.js, ip, sails.js, vps, host

I have a VPS with 10 IP directions and i need to configure an installation of Sails.js to run on only one IP direction. By default when i run the project with "sails lift" it runs on all IP directions and i dont want it.... I want to run all node projects in an specific IP. Thanks :)

root@c352 [/home/node/Shamman]# sails lift

info: Starting app...

info:
info:
info:    Sails.js           <|
info:    v0.9.16             |\
info:                       /|.\
info:                      / || \
info:                    ,'  |'  \
info:                 .-'.-==|/_--'
info:                 `--'-------'
info:    __---___--___---___--___---___--___
info:  ____---___--___---___--___---___--___-__
info:
info: Server lifted in`/home/node/Shamman`
info: To see your app, visit localhost:1337
info: To shut down Sails, press  + C at any time.

debug: --------------------------------------------------------
debug: :: Fri Dec 05 2014 15:44:32 GMT-0430 (VET)
debug:
debug: Environment      : development
debug: Port             : 1337
debug: --------------------------------------------------------

I want to change the host localhost to an specific IP direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can pass it the configuration variable `host` and `port`.

Just make that the IP address and port you want to bind to.

```
{
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 8080
}
```

Comment: Thanks I found the parameters in the local.js file add it's solved.